# Angular 6: Can't resolve all parameters for MainComponent in main.component.ts on importing ApiService

Tags: angular, typescript, angular6

I am having a problem importing my ApiService in a component. I just created a new app with `ng new` and created an API service using the CLI. Everything works fine but as soon as I import the service in a component, I get the error:

```
Can't resolve all parameters for MainComponent in <project_location>/src/app/main/main.component.ts
```

I got another error once but it never appeared again:

```
ERROR in node_modules/@angular/http/http.d.ts(1,1): error TS6053: File '<project_location>/node_modules/@angular/http/http.ngfactory.ts' not found.
src/app/api.service.ts(1,1): error TS6053: File '<project_location>/src/app/api.service.ngfactory.ts' not found.
```

Here are the files:

**api.service.ts**

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { environment } from '../environments/environment';
import { Http, Response, URLSearchParams } from '@angular/http';
import { map, catchError } from 'rxjs/operators';
import { throwError, Observable } from 'rxjs';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class ApiService {

  constructor(
    private http: Http
  ) { }

  get(path: string, params: URLSearchParams = new URLSearchParams()): Observable<any> {
    const url = environment.api_url + '/' + path;

    return this.http.get(url, { search: params })
      .pipe(map((res: Response) => res.json()), catchError((error: Response) => throwError(error.json())));
  }

  put(path: string, body: any): Observable<any> {
    const url = environment.api_url + '/' + path;

    return this.http.put(
      url,
      body
    )
    .pipe(map((res: Response) => res.json()), catchError((error: Response) => throwError(error.json())));
  }

  post(path: string, body: any): Observable<any> {

    const url = environment.api_url + '/' + path;
    return this.http.post(url,
      body
    )
    .pipe(map((res: Response) => res.json()), catchError((error: Response) => throwError(error.json())));
  }

  delete(path): Observable<any> {
    return this.http.delete(
      `${environment.api_url}${path}`
    )
    .pipe(map((res: Response) => res.json()), catchError((error: Response) => throwError(error.json())));
  }

  deleteitem(path: string, body: Object = {}): Observable<any> {
    const url = environment.api_url + '/' + path;

    return this.http.delete(
      url
    )
    .pipe(map((res: Response) => res.json()), catchError((error: Response) => throwError(error.json())));
  }
}
```

**main.component.ts**

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { ApiService } from '../api.service';


@Component({
  selector: 'app-main',
  templateUrl: './main.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./main.component.css']
})
export class MainComponent implements OnInit {

  constructor(
    public apiService = ApiService
  ) { }

  ngOnInit() {
  }

}
```

**app.module.ts**

```
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClientModule } from '@angular/common/http';

import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { MainComponent } from './main/main.component';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,
    MainComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    HttpClientModule
  ],
  providers: [],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

I didn't add ApiService to list of providers since I read on a StackOverflow thread that the file api.service.ts already has `providedIn: 'root'` mentioned, so it shouldn't be added to providers in app.module.ts.

**This is the Angular CLI Version**

```
     _                      _                 ____ _     ___
    / \   _ __   __ _ _   _| | __ _ _ __     / ___| |   |_ _|
   / △ \ | '_ \ / _` | | | | |/ _` | '__|   | |   | |    | |
  / ___ \| | | | (_| | |_| | | (_| | |      | |___| |___ | |
 /_/   \_\_| |_|\__, |\__,_|_|\__,_|_|       \____|_____|___|
                |___/


Angular CLI: 6.0.8
Node: 8.11.3
OS: linux x64
Angular: 6.1.10
... animations, common, compiler, compiler-cli, core, forms
... http, language-service, platform-browser
... platform-browser-dynamic, router

Package                           Version
-----------------------------------------------------------
@angular-devkit/architect         0.6.8
@angular-devkit/build-angular     0.6.8
@angular-devkit/build-optimizer   0.6.8
@angular-devkit/core              0.6.8
@angular-devkit/schematics        0.6.8
@angular/cli                      6.0.8
@ngtools/webpack                  6.0.8
@schematics/angular               0.6.8
@schematics/update                0.6.8
rxjs                              6.3.3
typescript                        2.7.2
webpack                           4.8.3
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have used `HttpClientModule` and tries to inject `Http` service. `Http` is deprecated service and is located into the `HttpModule` which is also deprecated.

You need to inject `HttpClient` service

```
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';

...

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class ApiService {

  constructor(
    private http: HttpClient
  ) { }

  ...
}
```

and change the `MainComponent`'s constructor

```
export class MainComponent implements OnInit {

  constructor(
    public apiService: ApiService
  ) { }

  ngOnInit() {
  }

}
```

Answer (score 2):

In `MainComponent.ts` Change

```
constructor(
    public apiService = ApiService
  ) { }
```

to

```
constructor(
    public apiService:ApiService
  ) { }
```